# Longest streak using Standard SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ansi-sql

I have a table with fields:

```
user_id
tracking_date
```

with values

```
1, 2017-12-23
2, 2017-12-23
1, 2017-12-24
1, 2017-12-25
2, 2017-12-26
3, 2017-12-26
1, 2017-12-27
2, 2017-12-27
```

I would like to find the longest streak for all users as of today. So o/p of above query comes in form:

```
1, 1
2, 2
3, 0
```

Is there a way to achieve this o/p in a single SQL query.

Comment: how would you define longest streak?

Comment: You could combine [this blog post](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/06/19/finding-the-longest-streak-using-sql-analytical-functions/) for finding the longest streak for users and [this forum post](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,243093) for converting LEAD into something MySQL recognizes

Comment: Is your expected output correct? I only can understand your question if output would be id:1 with streak:3, id:2 with streak 2, id:3 with streak 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  For each `user_id`, you want to get latest date where there is no record on the previous date and the most recent date:

```
select user_id,
       (case when max(tracking_date) <> current_date then 0
             else (current_date -
                   max(case when prev_td is distinct from tracking_date - interval '1 day'
                  )
        end) as seq
from (select t.*,
             lag(tracking_date) over (partition by user_id order by tracking_date) as prev_td
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Instead of getting the date, i am looking for count of all previous days

Comment: @user2077935 . . . This should return the count.